Ubuntu's grub menu
Grub menu in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Hello, I am new to Ubuntu and this community, so I do not have that much of knowledge.
I just perform clean disk and install the latest Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. When i turn the system on the grub menu appears and asks to select the OS even though I have completely removed windows.
So, I just want to know is there any option to turn the grub menu off in startup menu, and it should cause any internal issue.

Missing some details. What else is in the grub menu that you can select from?

You can reduce the time grub waits; but I'd recommend avoiding removing the grub menu completely; as it's useful if you have problems in the future, and need to use it (eg. a kernel upgrades causes a problem, you can reboot & select an older kernel at grub and thus boot into your system using that older kernel & explore the issue without the problem getting in the way).  Yes you can turn it off, but I'd not recommend it (unless you have a crystal ball and know you'll never encounter problems).

When you removed Windows, did you leave the /EFI/Microsoft folder in the ESP - efi system partition? That is what grub finds when looking for bootable Windows, whether that entry works or not. You can also turn off os-prober in grub's settings. sudoedit /etc/default/grub change this to true. "GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true"

@oldfred In my SSD there is a folder 'boot'. i.e - boot/efi/EFI/BOOT and ubuntu folder present.Microsoft folder is not available in efi and it still shows windows in boot manager.

@David Grub menu still shows windows even after removing it.

@guiverc I was thinking the same, Thanks.

ps:   The grub menu will remain the same until it's been told to rebuild; ie. after you've applied new kernel fixes (and thus details are changed; the upgrades will cause it to rebuild) OR you kick of rebuild yourself via sudo update-grub

@guiverc After running the command you mentioned , it says "Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ..."

Grub is finding Windows boot files in an ESP on sda1. Is Ubuntu using a different ESP? Generally you should only have one ESP per drive/device.

@oldfred Sorry for the confusion. I have one ESP. /boot/efi/EFI . Then inside EFI I have two folders i.e - BOOT and ubuntu. Inside BOOT I have three files 1.BOOTX64.EFI 2.fbx64.efi 3.mmx64.efi

If sudo update-grub is finding Windows, it is somwhere. You need to give us more details which this repair should provide. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

To not see the grub menu while booting:
when system start up open up a terminal and type
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

(type your root password)
and in the file, set
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0

save the file an quit with Ctrl + S (Save) and Ctrl + X (Quit)
and then update the grub config with
sudo update-grub

and reboot
